# How to color text in a cell containing a specific string using pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

After running my algorithms I saved all the data in an excel file using pandas.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Diff.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Now, some of the cells contain strings which includes "-->" in it. I have the row and column number for those cells using:

```
xl_rowcol_to_cell(rows[i],cols[i])
```

But I couldn't figure how to color those cells or atleast the whole text in it.

Any suggestions/tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a conditional format in Excel like this:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['foo', 'a --> b', 'bar']})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add a format. Light red fill with dark red text.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

# Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format(1, 1, len(df), 1,
                             {'type':     'text',
                              'criteria': 'containing',
                              'value':    '-->',
                              'format':   format1}) 

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

See [Adding Conditional Formatting to Dataframe output](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#adding-conditional-formatting-to-dataframe-output) in the XlsxWriter docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
def highlight (dataframe):

    if  dataframe[dataframe['c'].str.contains("-->")]:

        return ['background-color: yellow']*5
    else:
        return ['background-color: white']*5


df.style.apply(highlight, axis=1)
```

Comment: So,here,the dataframe would be - writer, as per my example? and df will be writer too?